# iOS MapboxMaps v10 and MapboxSearch SKD incompatibility issues

Tags: ios, cocoapods, mapbox, mapbox-ios

We have an iOS app that uses mapbox maps and mapbox search, and we are trying to port to v10 of mapbox maps.

Our original cocoa podfile looked like this (all working fine):

```
  pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK'
  pod 'MapboxSearch', '= 1.0.0-beta.3'
```

Following the [v10 install instructions](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/beta/maps/guides/install/) we updated the podfile to:

```
  pod 'MapboxMaps', '10.0.0-rc.1'
  pod 'MapboxSearch', ">= 1.0.0-beta.3", "< 2.0"
```

But get the following errors when we run 'pod install'

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
> "MapboxCommon":   In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
> MapboxCommon (= 9.0.2, ~> 9.0.0)
>
> In Podfile:
> MapboxMaps (= 10.0.0-rc.1) was resolved to 10.0.0-rc.1, which depends on
> MapboxCommon (~> 14.0.1)
>
> ```
> MapboxSearch (< 2.0, >= 1.0.0-beta.3) was resolved to 1.0.0-beta.3, which depends on
>   MapboxCommon (~> 9.0.0)
> ```
>
> Specs satisfying the `MapboxCommon (= 9.0.2, ~> 9.0.0), MapboxCommon (~> 14.0.1), MapboxCommon (~> 9.0.0)` dependency were found, but they
> required a higher minimum deployment target.

We also tried *pod 'MapboxSearch', '>= 1.0.0-beta.5.2'* and had similar compatibility issues.

**Does anyone know if there are compatible versions of these frameworks?**

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This versions seems to be compatible:

```
  pod 'MapboxMaps', '10.0.0-rc.3'
  pod 'MapboxSearch', '1.0.0-beta.7'
```